# How do I import my coinbase wallet to metamask

Tags: metamask, wallets, coinbase

I just installed metamask and when I click import it asks for a private key. I have no idea what that is from my coinbase wallet. All I see in my coinbase wallet is my 12 word phrase, where do I find the private key of my coinbase wallet?

Comment: Nice, this helped me out alot. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to log out. in order to do so, click on your account picture on the top right. then click on "lock". this will log you out of Metamask. after logging out, right before you enter your password to log in, on the bottom of the login page you can see a link that says "Import using account seed phrase".

Also, take note that Coinbase won't give you your private keys. So you can't import a Coinbase account to Metamask by the private key.

Comment: That worked, no clue why you need to logout for that but thanks!

Comment: @CoryHass You're welcome. if this answered your question. Please click on the "tick " icon next to the answer to accept it as an answer. This will inform future readers that there is an answer to this question that worked.